# CGMutablePathRef or SKShapeNode not in right position

Tags: sprite-kit

I am creating a SpritKit visualization for a component in my engine to aid with debugging and allow me to test features without the full graphics load.

My first goal is essentially to make sure that I can relate points in the "engine simulation" to SpriteKit primitives. To achieve this I am trying to draw a simple rectangle around the screen. I thought this would be simple but I am encountering the weirdest issue it is almost as if the coordinate system is wrong.

So in order to draw the rectangle (technically a hourglass just  I am doing the following code:

```
CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();
CGPathMoveToPoint(path, nil, 0, 0);
CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, nil, engineSize.width, 0);
CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, nil, engineSize.width , engineSize.height);
CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, nil, 0, engineSize.height );
CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, nil, 0, 0);
CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, nil, engineSize.width, engineSize.height);
CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, nil, 0, engineSize.height);
CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, nil, engineSize.width,0);
_engineBounds = [SKShapeNode shapeNodeWithPath:path];
_engineBounds.lineWidth = 20;
_engineBounds.strokeColor = UIColor.purpleColor;
_engineBounds.position = CGPointMake(self.view.frame.size.width * -0.5, self.view.frame.size.height * -0.5);
_engineBounds.zPosition = 1;
_engineBounds.fillColor = UIColor.greenColor;
[self addChild:_engineBounds];
```

The goal would be that in the CG calls I can put coordinates in terms of the engine coordinate system and have them display properly due to me moving the origin with position.

I do this drawing and set up the engine in `- (void)didMoveToView:(SKView *)view` inside of the default SpriteKit project.

```
Screen scr;
scr.width = self.view.frame.size.width;
scr.height = self.view.frame.size.height;
_testEngine->setScreen(scr);
[self visualizeEngineBounds];
```

However this is causing the following to happen 
[image]

You would think this means that the engine size is too big so I scale the engine initialization size down by 0.5 and this is what I get

[image]

Notice how the bottom left corner is still not in the right spot. It is almost as if the coordinate system is slightly shifted. Why is this happening?

Comment: What are the width and height values of `engineSize` and the scene?

Comment: You are not accounting for the screen cropping due to different aspect ratios

Comment: btw, your view size is not the same as your scene size.  You are using wrong measurements here

Comment: That is it! Setting ```CGRect sizeRect = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds;
    scene.size = sizeRect.size;
    scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;``` worked!